# Não consigo ir a Página

Tags: array, ionic, ionic3

Olá, aqui estou eu com mais uma dúvida.
Criei um projeto no ionic 3,  e tenho esse menu de perfil [image: menu], porém quando clico em cada item do menu , ( Agenda cultural, por região, blog..) não abre a página, está dando erro. 
Em app.html tem : `

```
    <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" [class.active]="checkActivePage(p)">
        <ion-icon name="{{p.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
        <font color="#088A85"><h6><b> {{p.title}}  </b></h6> </font>

    </button>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>`
```

e em app.component.ts  ` pages: Array<{title: string, icon:string, component: any}>;
  activePage: any;

constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

```
this.pages = [
  { title: 'Agenda Cultural', icon:'any', component: AgendaculturalPage },
  { title: 'Por região', icon:'any', component: PorregiaoPage },
  { title: 'Blog Vida Carioca', icon:'any', component: BlogvidacariocaPage },
  { title: 'Termos de uso', icon:'any', component: TermosdeusoPage },
  { title: 'Sobre o Vida Carioca', icon:'any', component: SobreovidacariocaPage },
  { title: 'Ajuda', icon:'any', component: AjudaPage },
  { title: 'Configurações', icon:'any', component: ConfiguracoesPage },
  { title: 'Meu Perfil', icon:'any', component: MeuperfilPage },
  { title: 'English Version', icon:'any', component: EnglishversionPage },
  { title: 'Sair', icon:'any', component: SairPage },
  { title: '', icon:'logo-facebook', component: FacebookPage },
  { title: '', icon:'logo-instagram', component: InstagramPage },

];

this.activePage = this.pages[0];
```

}`

Eu acredito que seja adicionando a página junto aos outros componentes em component.ts, mas não sei bem como fazer isso e nem se é isso. Se alguém souber algo e puder me ajudar, Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, era um pequeno erro,  faltava   "  '  '  "  para o component..

{ title: 'Agenda Cultural', icon:'any', component: 'AgendaculturalPage' },
  { title: 'Por região', icon:'any', component: 'PorregiaoPage' },